# My "RevNum" field is set to "2" by Word 2007 or SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office

After "check-in" of a `.docx` file to `SharePoint` and editing it the `RevNum` property is set to `2`.

This does not make sense, can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, revision 1 for the initial creation and revision 2 from the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the Document Version History by going to the Document Library Settings->Version Settings and selecting one of the following options

- No versioning
- Create major versions
- Create major and minor (draft) versions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers! It seems that I asked my question not accurate enough.

The problem is, that the **RevNum** is set **back to 2** *even it was higher before*:

1. **.docx** has **RevNum 31**
2. check out the document
3. change the document (**RevNum 32**)
4. change again (**RevNum 33**) ...
5. check into **SharePoint**
6. **RevNum 2**

I mean the **RevNum** "property" of **Word**, *not* **SharePoint**. A Revision number should be unique and incremented after each change.

*I assume that the following happens:*

When check-in happens the document is re-created (copied from local drafts folder to server location) and therefore the RevNum starts with 1, changes (?) and RevNum 2 ... Maybe it is a bug in SharePoint. "RevNum back to 2" only occurs when check in/out is used. When editing it "normaly" it increases the RevNum correctly.

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer on this question? It seems to be intermittant for me. Sometimes it works fine but most of the time it reset's the RevNum. I've tryed to not use a local copy as well but the problem remains.